# CONVERT_IMPLICIT when inserting a Geography datatype into a Geography datatype column on Temp Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb, spatial

```
@@Version
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) - 10.50.6220.0 (X64)
```

If I try to insert data into a `geography` datatype in a temp table I get a `CONVERT_IMPLICIT`, converting a `Geography` datatype to a `Geography` datatype?

```
DECLARE @xPolygon NVARCHAR(MAX) 
     = '53.835134 -2.474670, 53.812436 -0.288391, 52.417944 -0.090637, 52.270286 -3.018494, 53.835134 -2.474670'

CREATE TABLE #xSpatialTable (
     id         INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
    ,GeogCol1   geography 
);

INSERT INTO #xSpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES (geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON(( ' + @xPolygon + '))', 4326));
```

The Second Compute Scalar operator in the [actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1fAlJK-m) for Expr1005 shows this

```
Scalar Operator(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(geography,[geography]::STPolyFromText((N'POLYGON(( '+[@xPolygon])+N'))',(4326)),0))
```

There is no such `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` if I change to using a user table instead of a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.xSpatialTable (
     id         INT IDENTITY (1,1) 
    ,GeogCol1   geography 
);

INSERT INTO dbo.xSpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES (geography::STPolyFromText('POLYGON(( ' + @xPolygon + '))', 4326));
```

Here's the [actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkU2b1Fb7)

If I try the same test on a SQL 2014 database on the same machine, I don't get a `convert_implicit` whether I use a temp table or a user table.

Why the difference on 2008R2? and how do I get rid of the `Convert_Implicit` when using a temp table on 2008R2?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this has anything to do with the spatial extensions. I think this is this [problem here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0294e967-88c0-4711-bf47-08093c76994a/convertimplicit-with-bit-literals?forum=transactsql),

From that post, all these work without generating `CONVERT_IMPLICIT`

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE IsSomething = 'TRUE';

SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE IsSomething = Cast(1 as bit);

DECLARE @TRUE bit;
SELECT @TRUE = 1;
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE IsSomething = @TRUE;
```

You can read about [the reasons for this problem here.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0294e967-88c0-4711-bf47-08093c76994a/convertimplicit-with-bit-literals?forum=transactsql)

If it is the spatial type you may try a `CAST` to `VARBINARY(max)`.. `CAST( geography::STPolyFromText('') AS VARBINARY(max))`

---

If you can't afford to upgrade to a newer version of SQL Server, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) with [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) is perhaps an option as it is free and open source and has the best GIS implementation.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE xSpatialTable (
     id         int           PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
     GeogCol1   geography
);

INSERT INTO xSpatialTable (GeogCol1)
VALUES ( 'POLYGON((53.835134 -2.474670, 53.812436 -0.288391, 52.417944 -0.090637, 52.270286 -3.018494, 53.835134 -2.474670))' );
```

Comment: But why does the `convert_implicit` only occur with temp tables?

Comment: I'm confused at *how* I could ever tell you why the engine has a different route leading to an implicit_coercion error without the source code to SQL Server 2005. I can only speculate. My speculation is that it wants you to cast your int to a bit (because that's what it is in the table) -- if that still generates the error on the temp table, try casting the geog/geom to a VARBINARY(max) if that still generates the error -- I'm out of ideas. Run to PostgreSQL. There I have the source code. We can only speculate, and I tried my best. ;)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realise you were referring to SQL Engine code :-)